# How check if there is no duplicate values for a list of properties in an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, duplicates, key

```
const arr = \["key1", "key2", "key3"\];
```

example 1 :

`const obj = {key1 : "1", key2 : "2", key3 : "2", key4: "4", key5 : "5"};`

example 2

`const obj = {key1 : "1", key2 : "2", key3 : "3", key4: "4", key5 : "1"};`

I just want to know if there are duplicatevalue in my object for the key in **arr**

so for for example 1 it should return true because key2 & key3 are identical
and for example 2 it should return false because key1, key2 & key3 are different

what's the easiest way to do it in pure javascript (ecmascript)?

Comment: please accept an answer as the solution if it solves the problem to close the question

Answer (score 2):

- Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), get the list of object key-value pairs
- Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), get the pairs which keys are included in the list
- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), get the values of the above filtered pairs
- Using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), you can compare the length of the keys to that of unique values above

```js
const keysHaveDuplicateValues = (keys = [], obj = {}) => {
  const keyValues = Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([ key ]) => keys.includes(key))
    .map(([ key, value ]) => value);
  return keys.length === ( new Set(keyValues) ).size;
}

const 
  keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"],
  obj1 = {key1 : "1", key2 : "2", key3 : "2", key4: "4", key5 : "5"},
  obj2 = {key1 : "1", key2 : "2", key3 : "3", key4: "4", key5 : "1"};
console.log( keysHaveDuplicateValues(keys, obj1) );
console.log( keysHaveDuplicateValues(keys, obj2) );
```

Another solution to directly return false when iterating to an existing value:

```js
const keysHaveDuplicateValues = (keys = [], obj = {}) => {
  const set = new Set();
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if(keys.includes(key)) {
      if(!set.has(value)) {
        set.add(value);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const 
  keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"],
  obj1 = {key1 : "1", key2 : "2", key3 : "2", key4: "4", key5 : "5"},
  obj2 = {key1 : "1", key2 : "2", key3 : "3", key4: "4", key5 : "1"};
console.log( keysHaveDuplicateValues(keys, obj1) );
console.log( keysHaveDuplicateValues(keys, obj2) );
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer, as it is correct. My answer has a simple approach of looping the array in an old-school fashion.

Comment: @LajosArpad thanks, the second solution was inspired by your answer to limit to one loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop in a nested manner and see whether there are duplicates

```js
const obj1 = {key1 : "1", key2 : "2", key3 : "2", key4: "4", key5 : "3"};
const obj2 = {key1 : "1", key2 : "2", key3 : "3", key4: "4", key5 : "5"};

function hasDuplicate(obj) {
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < keys.length; j++) {
            if (obj[keys[i]] === obj[keys[j]]) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(hasDuplicate(obj1));
console.log(hasDuplicate(obj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one liner

```js
const obj1 = {key1 : "1", key2 : "2", key3 : "2", key4: "4", key5 : "5"};
const obj2 = {key1 : "1", key2 : "2", key3 : "3", key4: "4", key5 : "1"};
    
let duplicateElement = Object.entries(obj1).map(([key, value])=> obj2[key].includes(value));
    
console.log(duplicateElement);
```